# OpenLayers : 4326 ol.proj.transform not working

Tags: javascript, transform, openlayers, openlayers-3

### Issue

---

When I click on the map I want to transform the coordinates to format of *4326*. When I do this it seems the Latitude part of the array transforms fine, but the Longitude part is incorrect and not valid.

### Code

---

When I click on the Map, the *SingleClick* event fires, I then get the coordinates of where the user clicked:

**Example of pPointClicked = [-40364190.03366159, 7054830.416117247];**

```
session.Map.on('singleclick', function (e) {
    var pPointClicked = e.coordinate;
});
```

I try and transform these coordinates into *4326* by using the code below:

**Example of coord4326 = [-362.59768838343064, 53.38659640004323];**

```
session.Map.on('singleclick', function (e) {
    var pPointClicked = e.coordinate;

    var coord4326 = ol.proj.transform(pPointClicked, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
});
```

As you can see the first value in the transformed variable is **-362.59768838343064** which is incorrect? Does anyone know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformation seems to be working.  Here's what I think is happening: you are not within the "original extent" of your map, i.e. you panned west and wrapped the entire world at least twice.

Try zooming out completely, then pan at the "same" location to the east twice, then click again.  You should have the coordinate you're looking for.

Here's an other tip: the world extent, in `EPSG:3857`, is:

```
[
  -20037508.342789244,
  -20037508.342789244,
  20037508.342789244,
  20037508.342789244
]
```

`[-40364190.03366159, 7054830.416117247]` is out of that extent, but if you pan to wrap the world twice, you should get: `289173.348083102, 7054830.416117247]`, which is within the extent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a little confused to what you mean with your answer? "Try zooming out completely, then pan at the "Same" location to the east twice" ...

Comment: Open this example: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled-wrap-180.html.  Open your browser dev tool (F12).  Paste this to get the extent: map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()).  Pan west a lot and try to get the extent again.  You'll see that the further you "wrap" the world you'll see that the extent is not the 'same' for a given location.

Comment: It becomes obvious once we get it, but it's kinda hard to explain, right? :)  Glad to hear positive feedbacks.  Happy coding.